# My image doesnt scale to its right pixel

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Gonna ask for help coz this is making me crazy now. 
The background image doesn't seem to fit in my window size. Can't see what i'm missing in my code. I've tried changing some x and y and other parameters, tried searching too but it still doesn't work. Thanks!

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


def callback():
    mainmenu.deiconify


def genkeymenu():

    mainmenu.withdraw()
    generatemenu = tk.Toplevel(mainmenu)

    bg1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="key2.jpg")
    background_label = ttk.Label(generatemenu, image=bg1)
    background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
    background_label.image = bg1

    keynamelabel = ttk.Label(generatemenu, text="Enter your key name")

    keynameEntry = ttk.Entry(generatemenu)

    keynameButton = ttk.Button(generatemenu, text="Enter")


    check1024= Checkbutton(generatemenu, text="1024 bit")
    check2048= Checkbutton(generatemenu, text="2048 bit")
    check4096= Checkbutton(generatemenu, text="4096 bit")

    background_label.pack()

    keynamelabel.pack()
    keynameEntry.pack()
    keynameButton.pack()

    check1024.pack()
    check2048.pack()
    check4096.pack()

    generatemenu.title("Generate Key")
    ttk.eval('tk::PlaceWindow %s center' % generatemenu.winfo_pathname(generatemenu.winfo_id()))
    generatemenu.mainloop()

class Buttons:
    def __init__(self, buttons):
        self.buttons = buttons
        self.genkeybutton = Button(buttons, text= "Generate Key Pair", fg="black", command=genkeymenu)
        self.id = buttons.create_window(50, 100, width=0, height=0,window=self.genkeybutton)

mainmenu = tk.Tk()
mainmenu.minsize(width=600, height=400)

imgpath = "key.jpg"
img=Image.open(imgpath)
img=img.resize((600,400), Image.ANTIALIAS)
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)


buttons = tk.Canvas(mainmenu)
buttons.pack()
buttons.create_image(0, 0, image=photo)
Buttons(buttons)

mainmenu.title("RSA ENCRYPTION")
#mainmenu.wm_attributes('-type', 'splash')
#mainmenu.eval('tk::PlaceWindow %s center' % 
mainmenu.winfo_pathname(mainmenu.winfo_id()))
mainmenu.mainloop()
```

This is the part of the code that i have problem with:

```
class Buttons:
    def __init__(self, buttons):
        self.buttons = buttons
        self.genkeybutton = Button(buttons, text= "Generate Key Pair", fg="black", command=genkeymenu)
        self.id = buttons.create_window(50, 100, width=0, height=0,window=self.genkeybutton)

mainmenu = tk.Tk()
mainmenu.minsize(width=600, height=400)

imgpath = "key.jpg"
img=Image.open(imgpath)
img=img.resize((600,400), Image.ANTIALIAS)
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)


buttons = tk.Canvas(mainmenu)
buttons.pack()
buttons.create_image(0, 0, image=photo)
Buttons(buttons)

mainmenu.title("RSA ENCRYPTION")
#mainmenu.wm_attributes('-type', 'splash')
#mainmenu.eval('tk::PlaceWindow %s center' % 
mainmenu.winfo_pathname(mainmenu.winfo_id()))
mainmenu.mainloop()
```

Here is the screenshot of the problem:

[image: Here is the screenshot of the problem]

Comment: save a reference for your image  **background_label.image = bg1** before you use place layout  it **background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)**

Comment: check the parentesis for this to **mainmenu.winfo_pathname(mainmenu.winfo_id()))**

Comment: @ADWAN i've tried but the problem is not from the def genkeymenu. Should probably edit my post. Sorry! :)

Comment: variable ** mainmenu** is assigned to what check script again

Comment: is it for the root window or what

Comment: the variable mainmenu is the root window,

Comment: you've not created the root window ,create it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In place of this:

```
imgpath = "key2.jpg"
img=Image.open(imgpath)
img=img.resize((600,400), Image.ANTIALIAS)
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
```

do this :

```
imgpath = PhotoImage(file="key2.jpg")
img = Label(mainmenu, image=imgpath)
img.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
```

it will cover the background.Then comment this to see what am talking about `#buttons.create_image(0, 0, image=img)`

better still do for image in the canvas

```
buttons = tk.Canvas(mainmenu)
buttons.pack()
buttons.create_image(0, 0, image=imgpath)
Buttons(buttons)
```

**Full code below**

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


def callback():
    mainmenu.deiconify


def genkeymenu():

    mainmenu.withdraw()
    generatemenu = tk.Toplevel(mainmenu)

    bg1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="key2.jpg")
    background_label = ttk.Label(generatemenu, image=bg1)
    background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
    background_label.image = bg1

    keynamelabel = ttk.Label(generatemenu, text="Enter your key name")

    keynameEntry = ttk.Entry(generatemenu)

    keynameButton = ttk.Button(generatemenu, text="Enter")


    check1024= Checkbutton(generatemenu, text="1024 bit")
    check2048= Checkbutton(generatemenu, text="2048 bit")
    check4096= Checkbutton(generatemenu, text="4096 bit")

    background_label.pack()

    keynamelabel.pack()
    keynameEntry.pack()
    keynameButton.pack()

    check1024.pack()
    check2048.pack()
    check4096.pack()

    generatemenu.title("Generate Key")
    ttk.eval('tk::PlaceWindow %s center' % 
    generatemenu.winfo_pathname(generatemenu.winfo_id()))
   generatemenu.mainloop()

class Buttons:
    def __init__(self, buttons):
        self.buttons = buttons
        self.genkeybutton = Button(buttons, text= "Generate Key Pair", fg="black", command=genkeymenu)
        self.id = buttons.create_window(50, 100, width=0, height=0,window=self.genkeybutton)

mainmenu = tk.Tk()
mainmenu.minsize(width=600, height=400)

imgpath = PhotoImage(file="key2.jpg")
img = Label(mainmenu, image=imgpath)
img.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

buttons = tk.Canvas(mainmenu)
buttons.pack()
buttons.create_image(0, 0, image=imgpath)
Buttons(buttons)

mainmenu.title("RSA ENCRYPTION")
#mainmenu.wm_attributes('-type', 'splash')
#mainmenu.eval('tk::PlaceWindow %s center' %
mainmenu.winfo_pathname(mainmenu.winfo_id())
mainmenu.mainloop()
```

Comment: it works! Thankyou! But the button seems to have an frame or background. Just gotta find a way to make it transparent though.